# I want to send data with HTTP request from node js file to PHP file like AJAX but it is not working and i am not getting response from the other side

Tags: php, node.js

```
app.get('/curl', function(request, response) {


    var data = querystring.stringify({
        name : "bob"
    }); 

    var options = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 80,
        path: 'http://matricore.com/curl_data/index.php',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
        }

    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
        console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
            });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });

    req.write('data\n');
    req.write('data\n');
    response.send(data);
    req.end();


});
```

I have been trying to post some static data to some url but it's not working, need help.

Comment: There is issue with your `http.request`  https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with your http request. `Host` in options should be domain name and `path` is endpoint's relative path to domain name.

```
app.get('/curl', function(request, response) {
  var data = querystring.stringify({
      name : "bob"
  }); 

  var options = {
      host: 'matricore.com',
      port: 80,
      path: '/curl_data/index.php',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
         'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data)
     }
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(response) {
     console.log('STATUS: ' + response.statusCode);
     response.setEncoding('utf8');
     response.on('data', function (chunk) {
         console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
     });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
     console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });

  req.write('data\n');
  req.write('data\n');
  response.send(data);
  req.end();
});
```

**UPDATE 3**

This would work for sure

```
var request = require('request');

app.get('/curl', function (req, res) {
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        url:'http://matricore.com/curl_data/index.php', 
        form: {name:'bob'}
    },function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
        res.send(body);
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: thanx alot for ur reply.I tried it but its still not working @mukesh sharma

Comment: i am not able to navigate to the other file(url)

Comment: The code you shared, post data to `matricore.com/curl_data/index.php` and after successful post, it print body in console. So, try to `GET` `'/curl'` in your application and check if above mentioned behavior is observed.

Comment: app.get('/', function(request, response)..by doing this,it opens index page on localhost and prints body and data in console.it is also printing data on the localhost page but is not posting it to the url i want...   :(

Comment: so, you are saying that it is not posting data to `matricore.com/curl_data/index.php`. Right ?

Comment: yes this is exactly my problem.And i am working on heroku,this code isnt working there

Comment: and yes i skipped one thing...wen i checked log files in heroku,i got the error "cannot find module request"

Comment: TypeError: request is not a function
   at C:\node\practice\index.js:97:5
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\node\practice\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)    ...This is the error afteer i used REQUEST

Comment: Install request module first, `npm install request`

Comment: i have done it already  :(      i really am not able to understand that when i ran this code,npm install request,got the request folder in node_modules folder..but the error "request module not found" still persists.i am confused with package.json file.do we need to write the dependencies on our own or are they written when module is loaded

Comment: it is not working mukesh..           [ .....TypeError: request.post is not a function at C:\node\practice\index.js:83:10]

Comment: when you run `npm install request --save`, then it writes the dependency into `package.json` file. It is easy to install packages, if you have dependencies defined in `package.json` . In that case, you need to run only `npm install`. And I am not sure, why you are getting above mentioned error. I installed and ran above mentioned code and its working fine. Even attached screen shot.

Comment: i tried it,its giving me the same error.anyways thankyou for the help

Comment: Last effort, check this one.